# generating html, onclick button not doing anything

Tags: python, html, button, flask, onclick

I'm using Python and Flask to write a web app. In it, I display some HTML, ask the user to press a button, saying if everything looks correct, and if it does, I'd like to route them to a new function, with an argument, to continue processing and displaying HTML.

In generating the HTML (in it's own function), I have the following code (`puzzle1` is a separate string variable that I want to pass into `output()`):

```
button = "<button onclick=\"output(" + puzzle1 + ")\" class = \"btn success\">Yes</button>"`
return *otherHTMLStuff* + button + *otherHTMLStuff*`
```

The button shows up on the screen, but when I click it, nothing happens.
Alternatively, if I add an `href` to the button instead of the `onclick`, it works fine in pulling up the function via this route, but I can't figure out how to pass in the `puzzle1` string.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve here, but `onclick` is a javascript handler for the button that gets executed in your browser. It will call the `output()` javascript function. If the function doesn't exist in your `otherHTMLStuff` you will get a javascript error and it can appear like nothing is happening. So check your browser console for this error.

Also `href` is not a valid attribute on the [button element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp). And I would also consider using [templates](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/templates/) instead of concatenating html output like that.

Comment: Thanks! Got it figured out now.